# 404 error when trying to deploy page on github even though index.html is present

Tags: github, deployment, github-pages

I’m currently trying to deploy my page to github but I’m getting the following error.

If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.

I’m following the instructions and pasting the link https://mattfang1999.github.io/PUI2020/ like in the instructions. Doing something like https://mattfang1999.github.io/PUI2020/homework_5/index.html also doesn’t work.

The following is my git directory https://github.com/mattfang1999/PUI2020/tree/main/homework_5

Answer (score 0):

The github pages url schema is `<username>.github.io/<repo>`, so your URL will be https://mattfang1999.github.io/PUI2020.github.io/